# javascript: Check if a value exists in a complex object, which is greater than a given value

Tags: javascript, object

I have the following object in javascript:

```js
let tvshow = {
  id: 268592,
  name: 'The 100',
  status: 'Continuing',
  episodes: {
    '1': {
      '1': {
        airdate: '2014-03-20',
        file_size: 0,
        location: '',
        name: 'Pilot',
        quality: 'N/A',
        release_name: '',
        status: 'Skipped',
        subtitles: ''
      },
      '2': {
        airdate: '2014-03-27',
        etc: 'etc.'
      }
      '3': {
        airdate: '2052-03-27',
        etc: 'etc.'
      }
  },
};
```

I want to filter out all episodes with airing date in the future (airdate >= currentDate). Current date is calculated as:

```
let currentDate = new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 10);
```

After selection I want to keep only some information:

```
{id: 268592,
      name: 'The 100',
      status: 'Continuing',
      seasons: [1,2,3,4,5,6],
      episodes: [
        {season: 1,
         seasonEpisodes: [ {id: 3, etc: 'etc.'} ]
        }
    }
}
```

The solution I've succeeded with the help of [@Chris G](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5734311/chris-g)  (thanks very much!)

```js
        return {
          season: Number(seasonNumber),
          seasonEpisodes: seasonEpisodesArray
            .filter((episodeNumber) => {
              return (
                tvshow.episodes[seasonNumber][episodeNumber].airdate <
                currentDate
              );
            })
            .map((episodeNumber) => {
              return {
                episodeNumber: Number(episodeNumber),
                episodeName: tvshow.episodes[seasonNumber][episodeNumber].name,
                episodeStatus:
                  tvshow.episodes[seasonNumber][episodeNumber].status,
                episodeAirdate:
                  tvshow.episodes[seasonNumber][episodeNumber].airdate,
              };
            }),
        };
```

Comment: You need Object.entries() and Array.filter()

Comment: to make it clear - are you just filtering, or also re-arranging the data as you say here?

Comment: Filtering and then re-arranging.
At last, I've managed to solve it, I'll edit the question.